# get must declare a body it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I wrote the line of code below but the an error was highlighted, below:

> get must declare a body it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

I don't understand what the problem is? Why can't the set call a method without mucking up the `get`?

```
 public string NoteColour { get; set { SetFontColour(value); } }
```

Comment: Because it is not clear what the `get` should do. If it would auto-generate a field, this field could never be set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to supply an implementation for the `get` since the compiler only allowed auto-implemented properties if both the `get` and `set` have no implementation.

If you implement either of them, you have to give an implementation for the other one too.

I expect to have something like this:

```
 public string NoteColour { get { return GetFontColor(); } set { SetFontColour(value); } }
```

Comment: Whilst this fixes the compiler problem, it now creates a rather unpleasant misuse of a property as there's now a risk of violating the principle of least astonishment. The OP would be better off exposing `GetFontColor()` and `SetFontColour()` methods directly.

Comment: Not sure. For some purposes you want to have properties (they can be bound to the UI for example).

Comment: Ah, good point. You can tell I've not done any binding recently as I forgot that one.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that you need to provide the body for your `get` method. So if you have created property by your own then you have to implement either both get and set or none.

```
public string NoteColour 
{ 
   get 
   { 
     return GetMethod(); 
   } 
   set 
   { 
     SetFontColour(value); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't write a body for `get` and `set` a macro is called which adds an hidden private field for your property in order to store the actual value. This is needed because a property has no memory associated with it and simply acts like a method working on your class object. It gives you the convince not to write explecit getter or setter methods like in old times.

If you want to do custom things (others than simply encapsulate a field), you have to declare both bodys since the macro does not know which field it should return.

Just for completeness:

```
private string noteColor = string.Empty;

public string NoteColour
{
    get
    {
        return this.noteColor;
    }
    set
    {
        // add custom actions needed here
        this.noteColor = value;
    }
}
```